# How to get and edit a Wordpress Navigation block in code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Navigation block named 'Main' for my header menu. I need to create a plugin that can fetch this block and add or remove elements from it.

I used to call the `wp_get_nav_menu_object()` function to gather my menu, but with the new Wordpress version this does not work anymore since the navigation post type is not the same now.

I found that the content of the menu is the stored in one variable as a string in the database. (In wp_posts -> post_content)

Am I supposed to modify the whole content string if I want to edit my navigation from code ?